# AlarmManager não está repetindo

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Tenho um alarme que é acionado a cada 5 minutos, e ele chama um intentService para testar uma condição que se verdadeiro, manda notificação para o usuário, senão ele não faz nada.

Mas o intentService só está sendo chamado uma vez, e somente se eu abro o aplicativo (mesmo que aberto eu preciso reabrir), até coloquei para mandar uma notificação para o caso de ser falsa a condição para ter certeza de que é o alarmManager que não está se repetindo.

```
public class AlarmMgr {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    public void Alarm(Context context) {
            // Set the alarm here.
            PendingIntent alarmIntent;

            alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentA = new Intent(context, BlockFoundService.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentA, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    1000 * 60 * 5 , alarmIntent);
    }
    public void CancelAlarm (Context context){
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            Intent intentA = new Intent(context, BlockFoundService.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentA, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tive esse problema, qual API que você está usando? qual level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dessa forma o alarme não poderá nunca lançará o IntentService.

Você está a construir o PendingIntent com `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, que serve para lançar Broadcast Receivers. Para lançar um Service tem de usar `PendingIntent.getService()`.

Substitua

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast()(context, 0, intentA, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

por

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentA, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Mesmo assim ela não está repetindo, acontece apenas uma vez ao abrir o aplicativo.

Comment: Você está a lançar o IntentService em outro local que não através do AlarmManager? Qual a versão do Android onde está a executar a aplicação?

Comment: Tinha sim, estava meio escondido haha 
Obrigado pela ajuda! :)